Movie about three children abandoned at a motel by their parents
This movie is from the 1970s or 1980s.
It is about three kids - two boys and a girl. They are at a motel when they are abandoned by their parents. The mother may have been prostitute. 
The oldest brother tries to keep them fed and together, but eventually they are found and taken away. The sister and little brother are adopted, but the big brother is left behind. Once he's grown up, he tries to find them.
The sister may have ended up in the Military. I remember the little brother always wore a toque and when the oldest brother finally finds him, he's working someplace wearing a toque.

Can you tell us a genre for this movie, I'm guessing drama?

Solved 
"A Long Way Home"(1981 TV Movie)

You might want to elaborate, though, in which way this fits he details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

Can you "accept" your own answer for us. Thank you.
